# VBA "All" checkbox with listbox deselect loop issues

Tags: vba, checkbox, listbox, multi-select

I have a check box that is used for "ALL" (selected by default) selections in a muliselect listbox that is deselected when an item in the listbox is selected. I also coded it so when "ALL" is selected, then it clears the listbox selections and checks the box. It ends up looping through the different subs and makes it annoying for the user.

For instance, when I click an item in the listbox it selects that value, then deselects the checkbox. Since the checkbox is deselected, it goes back through the listbox and deselects the selected item. It loops between the two subs a couple times and ends up only working correctly half the time.

Can I prevent entering the other sub?
Is there better logic so it won't loop as it does?
or maybe an better method to achieve this?

Multiselect listbox:

```
Private Sub Mkts_Change()

If Me.cheMkts.Value = True Then
Me.cheMkts.Value = False
End If

End Sub
```

Checkbox:

```
Private Sub cheMkts_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To Mkts.ListCount - 1
If Me.Mkts.Selected(i) = True Then
    Me.Mkts.Selected(i) = False
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding an `If` statement around your `cheMtks_Click()`? 
This way when your code deselects it automatically it shouldn't trigger the loop.

```
Private Sub cheMkts_Click()
    If Me.cheMkts.Value = True Then
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To Mkts.ListCount - 1
            If Me.Mkts.Selected(i) = True Then
                Me.Mkts.Selected(i) = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, Ruben. That corrects the error on the one end, but I am still having issues on the other side. When I have a selection and click the "ALL" box it deselects the check.

I came up with this code, which works beautifully in combo to your suggestion, but only when I have one item selected. If there is anything more, then it still goofs up. Figured I would post to see if you or someone else could advise a solution for multiple selections.

```
Private Sub Mkts_Change()
Dim i As Integer, count As Integer

For i = 0 To Mkts.ListCount - 1
If Me.Mkts.Selected(i) = False Then
    count = count + 1
End If
Next


If Me.cheMkts.Value = True And count <> Mkts.ListCount Then
Me.cheMkts.Value = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When i execute the code on my end it works fine. Even with or without the adition you made in the post above. Is there prehaps something else changing the listbox or checkbox? 
Btw i think it would be better to add this anwser as a update to your question. You can just edit your question and add it there.